# Why are these parts in mesh not moving?

Tags: mesh, mirror

While doing mirrored proportional editing some mesh parts are not moving and IDK why... How can I fix this? (vis photo)
[image]

Comment: hard to say, maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: here it is[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=Y5adYo2A" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/Y5adYo2A/)

Comment: so what are the parts that are not moving?

Comment: you can see the triangle holes, they are not supposed to be there is supposed to be symmetrical ballish an image

Comment: if at one point it has lost it symmetry you can select all in Edit mode and in the header menu > Mesh > Symmetrize, then choose the axis in the Operator box